How can a "reversible" reaction occur both ways?
Take a general reaction $\ce{A -> B}$ with $\Delta G<0$, it must be the case that $\ce{B -> A}$ has $\Delta G > 0$ (or vice versa.)
Now, if the reaction is "reversible", i.e. $\ce{A <=> B}$, how can this be? Clearly, the reaction can proceed only in one direction spontaneously, and yet both directions occur simultaneously.
Note that I specifically start $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ away from equilibrium, so clearly one direction must be favoured to reach equilibrium and the other direction will not be spontaneous.
Furthermore, to my understanding, all reactions are actually reversible, it is only a question of $\ce{[A]}$ and $\ce{[B]}$.
So, my questions are:

What defines a reaction as "reversible" when we use this term?
How can both the forward and reverse reactions of a reversible reaction occur simultaneously?


Each individual reaction has no idea what is going on elsewhere in the system. H2O splits into H+OH and H+OH merge into H2O all the time. The two reactions are in dynamic equilibrium at a specific point. Dynamic means the front- and back-reactions keep taking place.

If we could go back in time and stop "spontaneity" from being introduced into chemistry... preferably along with "stability", "octet expansion" and maybe even "ionic" bond.

$\Delta G<0$ means $\pu{K < 1}$, not zero.

@JonCuster right, so actually both A to B and B to A are happening all the time and the direction, as indicated by delta G, is a statistical / macro property?

Yes and yes. The reaction rate is the net reaction rate, mutually subtracting the rates of forward and backward reactions.  Said from molecular point of view, they do not know, on which side of the equilibrium the system state is. They react at will. the minimum of $\Delta_e G$ is followed by the neat rate.


[OP] Take a general reaction A⟶B with ΔG<0, it must be the case that B⟶A has ΔG>0 (or vice versa.)

If you start with pure A, you'll make some B. If you start with pure B, you'll make some A. $\Delta_r G$ depends on the concentrations. If you start with a reaction mixture containing the standard concentration of both A and B, the sign of $\Delta_r G^\circ$ will determine if the reaction has to go forward or reverse to reach equilibrium.

[OP] What defines a reaction as "reversible" when we use this term?

It is reversible if at the microscopic level, there is some forward and some reverse reaction. This is hard to see at the macroscopic level. However, if the reaction reaches equilibrium (all species present, no more change in concentrations), you can infer it is a reversible reaction. If it goes to completion (at least one reactant used up), it is not reversible.

[OP] How can both the forward and reverse reactions of a reversible reaction occur simultaneously?

There are plenty of molecules available, so they can do different things. When the forward and the reverse reaction have the same speed, the reaction is at equilibrium. It looks like nothing is happening, but the individual molecules are behaving just as they were before equilibrium was attained.

[OP] Note that I specifically start A and B away from equilibrium, so clearly one direction must be favored to reach equilibrium and the other direction will not be spontaneous.

Yes, that is right. However, if you start on the other side of the equilibrium, the other direction will be favored. Because $\Delta_r G$ is concentration-dependent, this will be reflected in its value as well.

Materials are made of particles.
These particles, such as atoms, ions and molecules, act independently. They are in independent motion. Some move faster than others, though there is the concept of average thermal energy, related to temperature.
Some particles may be combining, and some may be splitting. Think of it as marriage -- people may combine for a while, split, and recombine differently.
As an example, at STP, some water ($\ce{H2O}$) molecules (about 1/10,000,000) break up into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions (this is simplified). On the other hand, some $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions combine back to $\ce{H2O}$.
When the rate of breaking up, and the rate of recombining are equal, we say the system is in equilibrium -- yet there is constant shifting of partners.
If we blasted water with gamma rays, a larger percentage would be ionized -- there is a new equilibrium, while the influx of energy is constant. If the ionizing radiation is removed, more $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions combine back to $\ce{H2O}$, eventually returning to the old point of equilibrium.

At equilibrium deltaG = 0 This means that the chemical potential of the products equals the chemical potential of the reactants. It also means from kinetic theory that the rates of forward and reverse reactions are equal. For this to happen there are some physical constraints; the mechanism must be such that the reverse reaction can happen. This restricts equilibrium to elementary reactions or possibly a short string of coupled elementary reactions. This is a consequence of microscopic reversibility the forward and reverse reactions at equilibrium have the same mechanism. The more complicated the reaction the less likely this is possible.
The Standard Free Energy, Delta G[0], is the Gibbs Free Energy [H-TS] change from
the condition that both products and reactants are in their standard states, activities = 1., to equilibrium. The standard free energy describes the reaction to and from the standard state and equilibrium. One direction from the standard state is spontaneous. The reverse of that reaction is from equilibrium to the standard state, not the reverse reaction from the standard state in the opposite direction. The actual direction is determined empirically or simply looked up in tables where another chemist[s] has done the work for us either by experiment, by Hess's Law calculations or even possibly from First Principles.
The reaction in one direction from the standard state reaches equilibrium and that equilibrium can be reached from either direction again illustrating the equal rates of forward and reverse reactions at equilibrium. This is effected by the interplay of energy and entropy and requires that an appropriate mechanism is operating. The reaction in the other direction from the standard state is a continuing distancing from equilibrium.
